# Show that the mapping $x^*\mapsto x^*(x)+r$ is weak$^*$ continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces, compactness

Currently I am reading [Behrend's $M$-Structure and Banach-Stone Theorem](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540095330). The author introduced the following terminology at page $44,$ definition $2.13.$

> Let $X$ be a Banach space, $x\in X, r\geq 0.$ Let 
>   $$K(x,r) = \{(x^*,x^*(x)+r)\in X^*\times \mathbb{R}: x^*\in B_{X^*}\}.$$

Then the author mentioned that $K(x,r)$ is weak$^*$-compact due to the following:

> Since $B_{X^*}$ is weak$^*$-compact and the mapping $x^*\mapsto x^*(x)+r$ is weak$^*$ continuous, therefore $K(x,r)$ is compact.

My question is,

> **Question**: How to show that the mapping $x^*\mapsto x^*(x)+r$ is weak$^*$ continuous?

To show the above, I think we need to show that if the net $\{x^*_\alpha\}_\alpha$ converges to $x^*$ in weak$^*$-topology, then $x_\alpha^*(x)+r$ converges to $x^*(x)+r$ in norm.

So by assumption, for any $x\in X,$ we have 
$$x^*_\alpha(x)\overset{|\cdot|}\to x^*(x).$$
Then 
$$|(x_\alpha^*(x)+r)-(x^*(x)+r)| = |x^*_\alpha(x)-x^*(x)|\to 0. $$
Therefore, the map is weak$^*$ continuous.

Is my reasoning correct?

EDITED: After proving that the mapping is weak$^*$ continuous, how to see that the set $K(x,r)$ is compact? Is it because the set $K(x,r)$  can be written as Cartesian product between domain and the range of the weak$^*$ continuous map, and since both domain and range are compact in their weak$^*$ topology, therefore by Tychonoff's theorem, the set $K(x,r)$ is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. "Weak$^*$-convergence" is a fancy name that makes sense for several reasons; but it is important to always remember that it is just pointwise convergence.

The set $K(x,r)$ is compact, being a continuous image of a compact set.

Comment: Thanks. I just notice that I do not see why the set $K(x,r)$ is compact. I have added this to my question. Can you explain to me why is it so?

Comment: Done. $\ \ \ \ $.

Comment: However, $K(x,r)$ is not a continuous image of a compact set right? What we have is that the function from $B_{X^*}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is weak$^*$ continuous and thus continuous image of $B_{X^*}$ is compact. How to determine that $K(x,r)$ is the image?

Comment: You have $K(x,r)=(\text{id}\times \gamma)(B_{X^*})$, where $\gamma:x^*\longmapsto x^*(x)+r$.

Comment: I suppose that the map $(id\times \gamma):B_{X^*}\to X^*\times\mathbb{R}$ is defined by $(id\times\gamma)(x^*) = (x^*,x^*(x)+r)?$ If so, then why is the map $(id\times \gamma)$ weak$^*$-to-weak$^*$ continuous? In particular, if $(x_\alpha^*)$ converges to $x^*$ weak $^*,$ I fail to see what am I suppose to prove here. I apologise for so many questions.

Comment: Well, you asked about compactness on $X^*\times\mathbb R$, but you never said what topology you are using. The easy/natural one is the product topology, which means coordinate convergence.